# match one observation in one data frame to every observation in another data frame without common variable

Tags: r

I would like to assign each value in df1 to every value in the df2

```
  df1 <- data.frame(TABLE = c(1, 2, 3)) 
  
  df2 <- data.frame(PERSON = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

desired output

[image]

Comment: Try `merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `expand.grid` function which creates a data.frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors.
To perfectly match the desired output, you need to put first person vector and then change the order of the columns. (Comment from @allan)

```
df1 <- data.frame(TABLE = c(1, 2, 3))

df2 <- data.frame(PERSON = c("A", "B", "C"))

expand.grid(PERSON = df2$PERSON, TABLE = df1$TABLE)[2:1]
#>   TABLE PERSON
#> 1     1      A
#> 2     1      B
#> 3     1      C
#> 4     2      A
#> 5     2      B
#> 6     2      C
#> 7     3      A
#> 8     3      B
#> 9     3      C
```

Comment: `expand.grid(PERSON = df2$PERSON, TABLE = df1$TABLE)[2:1]` would match the desired output perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2)
```

giving:

```
  TABLE PERSON
1     1      A
2     2      A
3     3      A
4     1      B
5     2      B
6     3      B
7     1      C
8     2      C
9     3      C
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `crossing`:

```
library(tidyr)

crossing(df1,df2)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  TABLE PERSON
  <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 A     
2     1 B     
3     1 C     
4     2 A     
5     2 B     
6     2 C     
7     3 A     
8     3 B     
9     3 C
```